# gyp errors when trying to install opencv node on mac mavericks trouble

Tags: macos, opencv, osx-mavericks, gyp

I am trying to install node opencv , i'm running mavericks on a mac. i run "npm install opencv" and have tried so many things to fix this problem but can't figure it out. 
here are my errors: there are also a bunch of warnings but this is the errors before it fails:

similar errors happen when i run node-gyp configure or node-gyp rebuild 
I tried to get help here: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3113
but it didn't help, I still get gyp errors

when running npm install opencv: here is the entire output

```
npm WARN package.json make@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/opencv
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/opencv

> opencv@0.4.0 preinstall /Users/gabriellalevine/ardrone-webflight/node_modules/opencv
> node-gyp clean rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/init.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/Matrix.o
../src/Matrix.cc:110:13: warning: variable 'mat' is used uninitialized whenever
      'if' condition is false [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
        } else if (args.Length() == 5) {
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/Matrix.cc:119:2: note: uninitialized use occurs here
        mat->Wrap(args.Holder());
        ^~~
../src/Matrix.cc:110:9: note: remove the 'if' if its condition is always true
        } else if (args.Length() == 5) {
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/Matrix.cc:104:13: note: initialize the variable 'mat' to silence this
      warning
        Matrix *mat;
                   ^
                    = nullptr
1 warning generated.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/OpenCV.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/CascadeClassifierWrap.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/Contours.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/Point.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/VideoCaptureWrap.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/CamShift.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/HighGUI.o
../src/HighGUI.cc:38:13: warning: variable 'win' is used uninitialized whenever
      'if' condition is false [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
        } else if (args.Length() == 2){
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/HighGUI.cc:42:2: note: uninitialized use occurs here
        win->Wrap(args.Holder());
        ^~~
../src/HighGUI.cc:38:9: note: remove the 'if' if its condition is always true
        } else if (args.Length() == 2){
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/HighGUI.cc:35:19: note: initialize the variable 'win' to silence this
      warning
  NamedWindow* win;
                  ^
                   = nullptr
1 warning generated.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/opencv/src/FaceRecognizer.o
../src/FaceRecognizer.cc:64:76: error: too many arguments to function call,
      expected at most 4, have 5
  ...f = cv::createLBPHFaceRecognizer(1, 8, 8, 8, 80.0);
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~             ^~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.0/include/opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp:951:16: note: 
      'createLBPHFaceRecognizer' declared here
    CV_EXPORTS Ptr<FaceRecognizer> createLBPHFaceRecognizer(int radius=1...
               ^
../src/FaceRecognizer.cc:90:42: error: too many arguments to function call,
      expected at most 4, have 5
      radius, neighbors, grid_x, grid_y, threshold
                                         ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.0/include/opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp:951:16: note: 
      'createLBPHFaceRecognizer' declared here
    CV_EXPORTS Ptr<FaceRecognizer> createLBPHFaceRecognizer(int radius=1...
               ^
../src/FaceRecognizer.cc:111:19: error: too many arguments to function call,
      expected at most single argument 'num_components', have 2 arguments
      components, threshold
                  ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.0/include/opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp:949:16: note: 
      'createEigenFaceRecognizer' declared here
    CV_EXPORTS Ptr<FaceRecognizer> createEigenFaceRecognizer(int num_com...
               ^
../src/FaceRecognizer.cc:132:19: error: too many arguments to function call,
      expected at most single argument 'num_components', have 2 arguments
      components, threshold
                  ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.0/include/opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp:950:16: note: 
      'createFisherFaceRecognizer' declared here
    CV_EXPORTS Ptr<FaceRecognizer> createFisherFaceRecognizer(int num_co...
               ^
../src/FaceRecognizer.cc:218:14: error: no member named 'update' in
      'cv::FaceRecognizer'
  self->rec->update(images, labels);
  ~~~~~~~~~  ^
../src/FaceRecognizer.cc:234:26: error: too many arguments to function call,
      expected single argument 'src', have 3 arguments
  self->rec->predict(im, predictedLabel, confidence);
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.0/include/opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp:931:9: note: 
      'predict' declared here
        virtual int predict(InputArray src) const = 0;
        ^
../src/FaceRecognizer.cc:273:26: error: no member named 'getMat' in
      'cv::FaceRecognizer'
  cv::Mat m = self->rec->getMat(key);
              ~~~~~~~~~  ^
7 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/opencv/src/FaceRecognizer.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "clean" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/gabriellalevine/ardrone-webflight/node_modules/opencv
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.20
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Is this all of the output, or is there anything else saying what those 7 errors were?

Comment: I pasted in the entire output now above ... thanks

Comment: Was your issue resolved? I have a similar issue (although I only get warnings instead of errors installing node-opencv). I tried installing old versions of opencv, but that didn't help because they fail the build process.

Answer (score 0):

Your errors are things like this:

```
../src/FaceRecognizer.cc:64:76: error: too many arguments to function call,
      expected at most 4, have 5
  ...f = cv::createLBPHFaceRecognizer(1, 8, 8, 8, 80.0);
```

So the OpenCV version you are compiling against is different from the one that the node module works with.

The fifth argument to `createLBPHFaceRecognizer` was added [in this opencv commit](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/cd7d93f3623ee13d94b39e8bf96f0617cd83196a), so it looks like you will need at least OpenCV `v2.4.3`, whereas you errors mention `v2.4.0`.

You should make sure your `brew` install is full up-to-date by running `brew update` and then `brew upgrade opencv` to pull in the most recent OpenCV from homebrew, which looks to be `v2.4.7.1`.

Comment: Really? What is all the gyp Err about ? Ok i'll try with older OpenCV version

Comment: @gabriella The `gyp` errors say `Error: 'make' failed with exit code: 2`. `make` is one of the tools that Node uses to compile modules from their source C++, so it is failing because of the C++ compilation errors.

Comment: ok thanks - i'm installing opencv 2.3.1 now. from the website , can i have two versions of opencv that you know of?

Comment: or rather, do you know how i can install 2.3.1 even though i have 2.4 now

Comment: I'm not sure what the best way is honestly.

Comment: 2.3.1 does not have face recognition

Comment: ok - i'm confused then, because this guy uses node + opencv+ face recognition : https://github.com/paulhayes/copterface - so i am going to ask him, but i'm assuming he is using opencv 2.4 . so i'm still perplexed why i can't install opencv using npm install opencv is that error truly mean i have to downgrade to opencv 2.3.1 or can it be something else?

Comment: @berak You are clearly right, sorry I've never used OpenCV. I was just going off the Node module README, which said `v2.3.1`. I've updated my answer with more steps.

Comment: Okay, looked into it even more. This is a bug in the Node module. It has a check for adding facial recognition when >2.4, but uses functions only available >2.4.3, so it fails if you are on 2.4.0,2.4.1 , or 2.4.2. Filed a bug: https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv/issues/96

Answer (score 0):

Hm, [in my case was not the same](https://github.com/erikusaj/checkOpenCV), but you can try the following.
Here is how I fixed OpenCV and npm opencv on Mac OS X:

1. install homebrew `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. install opencv `brew install homebrew/science/opencv`
3. install pkg-config: `brew install pkg-config`
4. Find location of file named *opencv.pc* by running `mdfind -name opencv.pc`
5. Run `nano .bash_profile` and add path found in step 4. to your Bash environment variables. Save file. Close and relaunch Terminal.

Example from my Mac:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12_2/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

You can check if configured by running `env | grep PKG_CONFIG_PATH` in your terminal.